# Simple Deno test fails with superoak

Tags: testing, deno

Context:
deno 1.13.2 (release, aarch64-apple-darwin) => on mac m1.
v8 9.3.345.11.
typescript 4.3.5

I'm very new with superoak and Deno tests, so I have just started with a very simple test... but this test fails.

```js
import { Application, Router, RouterContext } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v9.0.0/mod.ts";
import { superoak } from "https://deno.land/x/superoak@4.4.0/mod.ts";

const router = new Router();
router.get("/", (ctx: RouterContext) => {
  ctx.response.body = "Hello Deno!";
});

const app = new Application();
app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());

// Send simple GET request
Deno.test("it will allow you to make assertions if you await it", async () => {
  const request = await superoak(app);
  await request.get("/").expect(200).expect("Hello Deno!");
});
```

So, as you can see, it comes from the [superoak doc](https://deno.land/x/superoak@4.4.0#example).

My result is similar to [this issue on github](https://github.com/asos-craigmorten/superoak/issues/9#issuecomment-715417993), but I do an action after the get("/"). So, I don't see what I'm missing.

```
deno test --allow-env --allow-net ./src/app.test.ts
Check file:///Users/manu/workspace/zikstock-core/src/app.test.ts
running 1 test from file:///Users/manu/workspace/zikstock-core/src/app.test.ts
test it will allow you to make assertions if you await it ... FAILED (14ms)

failures:

it will allow you to make assertions if you await it
AssertionError: Test case is leaking async ops.
Before:
  - dispatched: 2
  - completed: 2
After:
  - dispatched: 11
  - completed: 10

Make sure to await all promises returned from Deno APIs before
finishing test case.
    at assert (deno:runtime/js/06_util.js:42:13)
    at asyncOpSanitizer (deno:runtime/js/40_testing.js:48:7)
    at async resourceSanitizer (deno:runtime/js/40_testing.js:72:7)
    at async exitSanitizer (deno:runtime/js/40_testing.js:99:9)
    at async runTest (deno:runtime/js/40_testing.js:215:7)
    at async Object.runTests (deno:runtime/js/40_testing.js:283:22)
    at async file:///Users/manu/workspace/zikstock-core/01336b7f-6f80-4dfc-a186-d813c04240e0$deno$test.js:4:1

failures:

    it will allow you to make assertions if you await it

test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out
```

My first surprise is that the test fails, even before having the error after the failures list.
Indeed, If I do a test which I known will fail, the result seems ok:

```js
Deno.test("it will allow you to make assertions if you await it", async () => {
  const request = await superoak(app);
  const result = await request.get("/");
  console.log(`Is the test ok? ${result.text === "Hello Deno!"}`);
  assert(result.text === "Hello Deno!");
});
```

Result:

```
deno test --allow-env --allow-net ./src/app.test.ts
Check file:///Users/manu/workspace/zikstock-core/src/app.test.ts
running 1 test from file:///Users/manu/workspace/zikstock-core/src/app.test.ts
test it will allow you to make assertions if you await it ...Is the test ok? true
 FAILED (14ms)
...
```

**I guess it's very easy to find but need help to see it :-) Anybody can help me?**

Comment: For now, my solution has been to move from oak to opine and superoak to superdeno. I works well.

Comment: This issue appears to be fixed in newer versions, as I can't reproduce it on Deno 1.19, oak 10.4 and superoak 4.6